# Get my saved progress back in Plants Vs Zombies 1

Tags: ios, plants-vs-zombies

I used to play this game a long time ago and it seems the progress is only saved on my old iPhone. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to transfer the files from your old iPhone.

PvZ1 did not have any cloud storage for the game. All files were stored locally. The only way that you *could* store the game's files on the cloud is doing so yourself, either storing them on Google Drive or somewhere similar.